# How to get text between underscore and dot in javascript

Tags: javascript

If I have a string like below:

```
1603202_15.jpg
```

I want to extract the text between the `_` and the `.`. Note that the string can have an arbitrary number of underscores in it, but there will only be one dot in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple string manipulation (assuming there is no `_` in the extension):

```
var result = str.substring(str.lastIndexOf('_') + 1, str.lastIndexOf('.'));
```

This assumes you want to get the string between the last `_` before the `.` (you could also use `str.indexOf('.')` btw.). If you want to get the string between the *first* `_`, just use `str.indexOf('_')` instead.

**Reference**: [`substring`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring), [`lastIndexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/lastIndexOf)

Answer (score 0):

```
var res = '1603202_15.jpg'.match(/_(\d+)\./)​​​​​​​​​;
console.log(res[1]);​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/zerkms/cpQR3/

PS: you need to check if `res` is not `null` before you access its 2nd element

PPS: if there could be *anything*, not just a numbers then use

```
var res = '1603202_15.jpg'.match(/_([^._]+)\./)​​​​​​​​​;
console.log(res[1]);​
```

Comment: Add `^` to your regexp for the "not"

Comment: @Michael Sazonov: oops, just a typo while replaced `\d`, thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
var result = txt.match( /_([a-zA-Z0-9+)\./ )[ 1 ]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var str = "123_456_789.jpg";
var value = str.substring(str.lastIndexOf("_") + 1 , str.indexOf("."));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var input='1603202_15.jpg';
var regex=/\_.*\./;
var result=regex.exec(input);
```

will give you _15. and then remove _ and . to get inner string.